# Convert from spherical angles to longitude and latitude

Tags: latitude-longitude, spherical-coordinate

I have some images extracted from a radar from Austria and a formula for the projections (the exercice says *The projection formulas map pixel locations to geographical coordinates*), that transforms pixels into `(phi, lambda)` which the exercise states that are the **spherical angles**.

```
PRODUCT-PH-FORMS   =     "(1.570796326795-2*atan(0.404026225835*pow((1/sin(acotan(5899179.2/\
((5676531.8*pow((tan((1.570796326795-(v1*0.017453292520))/2)/\
0.373884679485),0.737361597616)*sin(0.012869387656*(v0-13.333333333))-\
v3*v4)+COL*v4)-((6380000.0*(0.924636243305-0.889738536848*pow((tan((\
1.570796326795-(v1*0.017453292520))/2)/0.373884679485),0.737361597616)*\
cos(0.012869387656*(v0-13.333333333)))+v2*v5)-ROW*v5)/((5676531.8*\
pow((tan((1.570796326795-(v1*0.017453292520))/2)/0.373884679485),\
0.737361597616)*sin(0.012869387656*(v0-13.333333333))-v3*v4)+COL*v4))))*\
((5676531.8*pow((tan((1.570796326795-(v1*0.017453292520))/2)/\
0.373884679485),0.737361597616)*sin(0.012869387656*(v0-13.333333333))-\
v3*v4)+COL*v4)/6380000.0*0.737361597616/sin(0.767944870878),1/\
0.737361597616)))"

PRODUCT-LA-FORMS   = f(pixel row, pixel col, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
```

But this gives very small values which cannot be `(latitude, longitude)` so I am looking for the transformation between spherical angles `(phi,lambda)` to `(latitude,longitude)`

For the result I need to provide `(latitude, longitude)` so how this conversion could be made?
The exercise provides me as well with some data I do not understand, which may be necessary:

```
v0=8.194 (reference lon)
v1=50.437 (reference lat)
v2 = 0
v3 = 0
v4=1018.18 (meter / pixel)
v5=1018.18 (meter / pixel)
```

This variables are used for the transformation formulas but may be useful as well to obtain `(latitude, longitude)`

---

### EDIT

I have tried to directly consider the values I obtain from the transformation as (latitude, longitude) after `*180/pi` but the coordinates I get are not in Austria

Comment: it was a mistype but thanks, you are right

Comment: From what I understand, you are given angular coordinates of radar with base coordinates of radar detector itself, The formula calculates offset of coordinates which then needs to be added to base coordinates for absolute coordinates. Its called [radar scan conversion](https://www.radartutorial.eu/12.scopes/sc17.en.html), someone with radar knowledge or coordinate system will be definitely clear how they actually calculate coordinates from scanned data. Keep in mind different system have different approach to calculate distances. Also, having small coordinates makes sense this way.

Comment: Thanks @MaulikParmar . So you would say I just have to get the PRODUCT-PH-FORMS and PRODUCT-LA-FORMS and add it to v0 and v1?

Comment: since you have mentioned it projects to (phi,lambda) which is giving you polar(spherical) coordinates so you cannot add them directly. It needs to  convert into lat/lon from (ph,la,height) to (x,y).in case of earth, H would be either earth's radius or detectors range. if coordinates are absolute i.e. relative to earth you can use directly or if it's relative to device, you do conversion and add offsets to coordinates. Map of Austria Falls between @47.2139456~48.8928648 & 7.8177826~15.8707611 anything more than these values are outside it's region.

Comment: The information I have is just the one I have described, nothing else, so I do not know height radar or specs of radar and still I havent found the way to find the good transformation